# PropertyResource injection from execution directory?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using `Spring` to inject a resource file from `src/main/resources` with:

`@PropertySource("classpath:/app1/abc.properties")`

Now I'd like to move the file to the root of the excution directory, thus outside the jar. So that properties can be modified without having to alter the jar.
How can this be done?

Comment: Prefix with `file:`. Spring normal resource loading rules still apply for `@PropertySource` annotations.

Comment: Wow that's great and works. You might add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `@Propertysource` springs normal resource loading rules still apply.

Instead of prefixing with `classpath:` prefix with `file:`.